# Identify if the data is a dataframe or a list of dataframes in a function

Tags: pandas

I have some calculations that I'd like to run and I've wrapped it into a function. However, my data sometimes can be a dataframe or a dataframe list. From my understanding , they iterate differently. I don't know how to include this logic in my function.

example data

```
d2 = {'id': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], 'is_free': [True, True, False, False, False], 'level': ['Top', 'High', 'Top', 'Top', 'Low']}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df_list = [d1, d2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

The function: I tried to let the function identifying if df or df_list=None before running the calculation.

```
def calculation(df_list=None, df=None):
    if df != None:
        df['result'] = df['level'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x == 'Top' else '0')
    elif df_list != None:
        for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
            df['result'] = df['level'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x == 'Top' else '0')
```

There are two issues:

1. `calculation(df_list=df_list, df=None)` returns expected result, but `calculation(df_list=None, df=df)` returns `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`
2. I'd like to avoid writing the calculation (`df['result'] = df['level'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x == 'Top' else '0')`) twice to keep the function concise as the real calculation is long.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the type of input in the `calculation` function and take a different action based on that:

```py
def calculation(df):
    if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        df['result'] = df['level'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x == 'Top' else '0')
    elif isinstance(df, (list, tuple)):
        list(map(calculation, df))
    else:
        raise TypeError(f'Unknown type: {type(df)}')
```

In case the input is a `list` or a `tuple`, you will recursively call `calculation` on every item of the input. If the input is a `DataFrame`, you can apply your function to it (this is the base case of the recursion).

If you have:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], 'is_free': [True, True, False, False, False], 'level': ['Top', 'High', 'Top', 'Top', 'Low']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], 'is_free': [True, True, False, False, False], 'level': ['Top', 'Top', 'Top', 'High', 'Low']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], 'is_free': [True, True, False, False, False], 'level': ['High', 'Top', 'Low', 'High', 'Low']})
df_list = [df1, df2]
df_list_nested = [df1, [df2, df3]]
```

And run `calculation(df1)`, you get:

```sh
df1
   id  is_free level result
0   1     True   Top      1
1   3     True  High      0
2   4    False   Top      1
3   5    False   Top      1
4   7    False   Low      0

df2
   id  is_free level
0   1     True   Top
1   3     True   Top
2   4    False   Top
3   5    False  High
4   7    False   Low

df3
   id  is_free level
0   1     True  High
1   3     True   Top
2   4    False   Low
3   5    False  High
4   7    False   Low
```

On the other hand, `calculation(df_list)` will change `df1` and `df2`:

```sh
df1
   id  is_free level result
0   1     True   Top      1
1   3     True  High      0
2   4    False   Top      1
3   5    False   Top      1
4   7    False   Low      0

df2
   id  is_free level result
0   1     True   Top      1
1   3     True   Top      1
2   4    False   Top      1
3   5    False  High      0
4   7    False   Low      0

df3
   id  is_free level
0   1     True  High
1   3     True   Top
2   4    False   Low
3   5    False  High
4   7    False   Low
```

But the function will work even with nested lists, like `df_list_nested`; `calculation(df_list_nested)` will change all the lists:

```sh
df1
   id  is_free level result
0   1     True   Top      1
1   3     True  High      0
2   4    False   Top      1
3   5    False   Top      1
4   7    False   Low      0

df2
   id  is_free level result
0   1     True   Top      1
1   3     True   Top      1
2   4    False   Top      1
3   5    False  High      0
4   7    False   Low      0

df3
   id  is_free level result
0   1     True  High      0
1   3     True   Top      1
2   4    False   Low      0
3   5    False  High      0
4   7    False   Low      0
```

Comment: may I ask what does the `list` in `list(map(calculation, df))` do ?  does is list each dataframe in the dataframe list ? thanks

Comment: [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator that applies its first argument (a function) to all the items of its second argument (an iterable); `list` is used to consume the iterator returned by `map` so that `calculation` is actually applied to all the items of `df` (here `df` is a list of `DataFrame` instances). The resulting list is not used, because `calculation` is based on a *side effect* (it modified the input `DataFrame`s) and it does return nothing.